# Modify/Patch json with another json using JQ

Tags: json, internationalization, translation, jq

Given two json files like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Item 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Item 2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Item 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this:

```
[
  "Item 1 translated",
  "Item 2 translated",
  "Item 3 translated"
]
```

— is it possible to apply the latter as a patch for the former? So that the final result would look like:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Item 1 translated"
    },
    {
      "name": "Item 2 translated"
    },
    {
      "name": "Item 3 translated"
    }
  ]
}
```

A use case. Imagine a huge json file which needs to be localized. We could just export data to be translated in CSV, edit them in Spreadsheets and then export to json back. Then we could apply it as a patch for the original json.

Answer (score 1):

In brief:

```
$ jq -s -f patch.jq object.json array.json
```

where patch.jq contains:

```
.[1] as $array
| .[0]
| .items |= reduce range(0;length) as $i (.; 
              .[$i].name = $array[$i])
```

In long: there are many alternatives to the above but using the "-s" command-line option has the advantage that it works with all versions of jq, and doesn't require bash-magic.

### Dictionaries

Rather than using an array as a dictionary, it might be better to use a dictionary, i.e. a JSON object. For example, in the present case, the dictionary could be constructed along the lines of:

```
{"Item1": "Item 1 translated", ...}
```

Of course there are pros and cons to be considered, but if you're worried about the case in which keys are of mixed type (e.g. `"1"` and `1`), then you could consider using a dictionary of dictionaries, e.g. along the lines of:

```
{ "string": {"1": "one}, "number": {"1": 1} }
```